# Do I need to create JSON Web Tokens for only mobile app API backend?

Tags: android, ios, node.js

I'm creating a backend for a mobile app with NodeJS and I wonder do I need to create JSON Web Tokens like on web app? The way my app works is

```
 after user login -> API return user unique id -> store that Id with UserDefaults in iOS 
 and use it to make request to API
```

Any suggestions on this one?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Is it like primary key in db ? If that is the case what will you do if you want to force logout user ? What if the key is stolen somehow ? Think about unhappy cases.